# How to set UILabel.text is equal to a number in iOS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I'm trying to set

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object valueForKeyPath:"@foo"]
```

Equal to a number. I can set a string in this field but not a number.

**But my error is:**

- Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSInvalidArgumentException`', reason: '`-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly assign an `NSNumber` to an `NSString` value (the label's `text` property).

You need to convert the number to a string first.

The best option is to use an `NSNumberFormatter` so the number appears properly given the user's locale.

```
NSNumber *val = object[@"foo"];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
// configure the formatter as needed
NSString *str = [formatter stringFromNumber:val];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = str;
```

Though you may get acceptable results by simply doing:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [object[@"foo"] stringValue];
```